# MutiArray Pushing error

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let evenOdd = (array) => {
  let newArray = [[],[]];

  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      newArray[0][0].push(array[i]);
    } else {
      newArray[0][1].push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Expected:
INPUT: evenOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
OUTPUT: [ [2,4,6], [1,3,5] ]

Sorry im new to coding. Not sure why This  doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
const oddEven = array => [
    array.filter(e => e%2),
    array.filter(e => !(e%2))

];
```

Comment: Good approach, but not optimal because it will loop the array twice.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to remove the second access:**

```
newArray[0][0].push(array[i]);
            ^
```

```js
let evenOdd = (array) => {
  let newArray = [[],[]];

  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      newArray[0].push(array[i]);
    } else {
      newArray[1].push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(evenOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Using function `reduce`

```js
let evenOdd = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c % 2 === 0) a[0].push(c);
    else a[1].push(c);
    
    return a;
  }, [[], []]);
}

console.log(evenOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify index for inner array, updated code:

```
var evenOdd = function(array) {
    var newArray = [[], []];

    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            newArray[0].push(array[i]);
        } else {
            newArray[1].push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(evenOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```